# Changing Javascript of the browser - Firefox

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox

Just like we can change browsers user-agent with some add-on, is there any add-on or way to change browsers Javascript that shows in whoer.net?

~

Comment: Most browsers offer a setting to disable _JavaScript_. If you want to run code for a specific version, you can set that in the _language_ attribute, but this isn't advised - instead it is advised to check for feature support.

Comment: @PaulS. I don't want to disable it, I want to change it to something else. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable javascript in mozilla firefox, then yes indeed that's possible. Here is the official article [explaining it](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages).

Comment: I don't want to disable it, I want to change it to something else. Thanks

Comment: Javascript is a language, there is nothing to change about it. You can disable javascript and in theory set up a different javascript engine if so you would wish (it would require a huge amount of working but in theory you could replace spidermonkey with v8 or something)